# How to start and register a chaincode of Hyperledger on Windows10

Tags: powershell, docker, docker-compose, blockchain, hyperledger

I am trying to start a chaincode on Windows10 operating system. According to the document, after running `docker-compose -f single-peer-ca.yaml up`, a command like this

```
CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051 ./chaincode_example02
```

will start the chaincode and a message  “Received REGISTERED, ready for invocations” will be reveived. On my linux environment, everything goes well, but on my Windows, when I input the command above into Powershell,

> CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc : The term 'CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> +CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051 ./chaincod ...
>
> +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> +CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc:String)[], CommandNotFoundException
>
> +FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Obviously, Powershell doesn't recognize the command directly as terminal of linux. So, what command should I run ?

I have tried

```
docker run --name=node_vp0 -e CORE_CHAINCODE_IF_NAME=mycc -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051 .\chaincode_example02
```

But Powershell gave me

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error parsing reference: ".\\chaincode_example02" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format.
```

Comment: Try using the `git bash` terminal

Comment: @RaghavSood It works, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To register a chaincode on Windows 10 (in docker container), you need to be in the container

For this, open a command prompt and go to bash shell using docker command :

```
docker exec -it [peer-container-name] /bin/bash
```

This will enable you to use linux commands and register chaincode.